# What is the best way to send authentication params while loading webview in android(Headers vs url params)

Tags: android, webview

context:

I am loading a webpage in android Webview. The webpage I am loading requires auth-token and user_id.

What is the best way to send authentication params while loading Webview in android

I have two options:

1. Send via headers by overriding HEADERS
2. Send via Url parameters

Which one would you guys suggest wrt ease of doing, security etc?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use POST method to send that authentication data to server. If possible use HTTPS protocol and encrypt your data, so it will be more secure.

For send data via url parameters(GET), i think it is a very bad practice, since everyone that know your url can directly modify it. Although POST can be hijacked too, as long as you encrypt the data and use HTTPS protocol, it will be very hard to crack the data